# Make phone calls programmatically on android

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

Is there any possibility to make phone calls without using the default phone app with intents?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy. You can start learning the source code from [com.android.phone.PhoneGlobals](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.4.2_r1/com/android/phone/PhoneGlobals.java?av=f), and read all relevant source code in `com.android.internal.telephony` and `com.android.phone`

Comment: But it seems that it won't allow me to build an app on top of the Android system, right? There is no interface to communicate with

Comment: Ah okay. But can we then also choose what data is going to be send?